# A necessary condition is .. or are?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammatical-number

Which one of the following is the correct form? For some reason, I have trouble understanding whether the correct form depends on "a necessary condition" (is) or "changes" (are).

> A necessary condition are training-induced changes in ...

or

> A necessary condition is training-induced changes in ..

What is the logic to decide which one is correct?

Comment: The subject of the sentence is the noun phrase _a necessary condition_. _A_ can only be used with a singular noun phrase. SIngular noun phrases acting as subjects take singular verbs. _Are_ is not a singular verb, but _is_ is. You figure it out.

Comment: To reduce confusion caused by distracting details, simplify the examples, then judge.  "A condition is/are changes."

Answer (score 1):

"A necessary condition" is the subject and it is singular, so the correct verb is "is".